# Please help me correct these sentences. Thank you!

Tags: grammar, sentence

1. The number of cars produced in the UK showed an upward trend.

Personally, I don't think "number" can "show" anything as this noun is inanimate.

2. The UK witnessed an increase in the amount of money spent on books, reaching a peak of $95 million in 2007.

I feel that the phrase after the comma is grammatically incorrect because the main subject mentioned here is "The UK"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I think **1** is acceptable, though I understand your qualms. Perhaps you'd prefer: *There was an upward trend in the number of cars produced in the UK.* **2** would be better without the comma. Then it's clear it was the amount of money that reached a peak: not the UK. Or you could say, *The UK witnessed an increase in the amount of money spent on books **to a** peak of $95 million in 2007*. (Are you sure you want $, not £ btw?)

Comment: If the examples are from newspapers, they get a pass for their own style...healdinese. It's all an attempt to bring dry material to life, yes by animating the inanimate. So numbers do show, drive, impress, overwhelm, and other dramatic stuff.

Comment: :-) Yeah, Yosef. +1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sentence 1 sounds awkward to me because the upward trend is something which is present in the data on the number of cars. It is typical to say numbers or data "show" a conclusion which is supported by the data. Such an example would be:

> 1. The increasing number of cars produced in the UK showed that demand continued to increase. [or some other conclusion supported by an increase in car production]

If the author merely wants to point out the upward trend in cars produced, it would be more natural to remove the verb "shows" and write of the trend in the numbers themselves.

> 1. The number of cars produced in the UK trended upwards.

If the author wishes to indicate that the upward trend is still happening, then they could change the sentence to "is trending upwards" or "continues its upward trend."

Sentence 2 is a bit awkward for the reason you mentioned. One possible fix is to add the word "which" to the clause after the comma to indicate a change in subject:

> 2. The UK witnessed an increase in the amount of money spent on books, which reached a peak of $95 million in 2007.

Comment: The ideas expressed by the sentences can be rewritten any number of ways- which one is the *best* is a matter of opinion.  The question asks how to ***correct*** the sentences.  An answer should therefore describe what’s actually wrong, not what  might, style-wise, be improved.

Comment: @Jim - Thank you for your feedback. I have edited my answer in an attempt to address your criticism.

Comment: Thanks for your support!

Comment: @Bonnie - Happy to be of help! If you have further questions, please let me know. 
If you are satisfied with my answer, I'd appreciate if you accepted it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.